# ham0 interface?

Tags: networking

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10 and a new interface appears in ifconfig: ham0 with ip address 25.130.234.51. I don't find any information on ham0 but it seems to have something to do with wireless. However, this desktop PC does not have any such hardware installed. Even more mysterious is the IP address. The normal interface is eth0 which is connected to my local LAN with address range 192.168.1.*.

So what is ham0 and how does it get the IP address?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you have install the [logmein-hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/US/labs/)

it's LogMeIn Hamachi VPN tunneling engie logmein-hamachi

Comment: Yes this is the answer.